# How do I create a widget for my armature

Tags: rigging

I made a simple door with a one-bone armature that allows it to swing plus/minus 90 degrees, and I wanted to have a widget to grab while posing it, instead of using the bone itself. Something like arrows pointing in the direction of each axis.

[image: Custom Widget]

How would I assign such an object to the armature so that when in pose mode, I see and manipulate it instead of the bone?

I've seen UI in other rigs (Pitchipoy, etc.), but I can't tell how they're set up for this. There's a *Custom Shape* property in the bone panel, but it seems to replace the model for the bone itself, whereas I'm looking for a sort of proxy for that bone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be one way to create a custom shape to control your bones: create a custom bone. https://youtu.be/6aRdurh30f0?t=1m9s

However, I'm sure you're more interested in this way, creating a custom shape that can control an aspect of a bone (like how the arrows in your image control the rotation of the door). https://youtu.be/8-IkdjzyJMQ?t=23m4s

Hope this helps!

Comment: The second link illuminated the solution. What I didn't realize is that my reference rig is using a dummy bone for the shape; that's why I didn't see a custom shape assigned to the primary bone. So my question was based on incomplete knowledge, and your suggestion does produce the desired result. Not sure why you got downvoted, but I upvoted you.

Comment: Is it possible you could provide an at least an outline of how to perform the techniques described in these videos? Links are great, but try to avoid relying on them. If anything happens to the linked content, the answer goes up in smoke. Thanks :)

Comment: The short of it is this: Create a shape (some vertices strung together, like my OP image), then assign that object as a Custom Shape for the bone. You'll likely need to muck with origin, offset, scale, etc. Or you can create another "dummy" bone which copies the position of the control bone, assign the shape to that, then assign the dummy as a custom shape for the control bone. The latter method gives a bit more flexibility for position and scale.